# Remove an image from "Asset Library"

Tags: lightning

Can anyone tell me how I can remove an image from "Asset Library"? I did a lot of research, but I cannot see any delete/remove button anywhere! (not even in the Edit File Details page)
App Launcher --> File --> Asset Library

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try below clickpath

Setup> QuickFind> Salesforce Files> Asset Files > You should be able to see the delete option. Make sure the dependencies are removed if any before deletion

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Swetha. Actually I had tried that way too, but some files cannot be deleted from there either(like the welcome image that I shared). When I click on "Del", it says: "This asset file is referenced elsewhere in salesforce.com. Remove the usage and try again." and when I go to the section that it's addressing, It's still not removable! I'm absolutely sure that I have deleted all the references to this image, but it keeps saying that it's being used somewhere else.

Comment: Can you try the steps listed in [article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000393209&type=1)

Comment: I have followed these steps before, that's where I started my question with. I guess it doesn't understand that I'm not using this image anymore! But anyway, thank you Swetha!